# Sklearn's roc_auc_score for multilabel binary classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn

REPHRASED WITH MWE:

I am trying to compute `roc_auc_score`.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Feb22so.py", line 58, in <module>
    test_roc_vals(od)   
  File "Feb22so.py", line 29, in test_roc_vals
    roc_values.append(roc_auc_score(target, pred))
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 260, in roc_auc_score
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/base.py", line 127, in _average_binary_score
    sample_weight=score_weight)
  File "/user/pkgs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 251, in _binary_roc_auc_score
    raise ValueError("Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score "
ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.
```

Here is an MWE version of my code.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

def test_roc_vals(od):
        #od will be an OrderedDict with integer keys and scipy.sparse.csr_matrix OR list values
        #if the value is a list, it will be empty.
        #a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix may have only 0s or only 1s
        roc_values = []
        for i in range(len(od.keys())-1):
                print "i is: ", i,
                target = od[od.keys()[i+1]]
                pred = od[od.keys()[i]]

                if isinstance(target, list) or isinstance(pred, list):
                        print 'one of them is a list: cannot compute roc_auc_score'
                        continue
                else:   
                        target = target.toarray()
                        pred = pred.toarray()
                        if len(np.unique(target)) != 2 or len(np.unique(pred)) !=2:
                                print 'either target or pred or both contain only one class: cannot compute roc_auc_score'
                                continue
                        else:   
                                roc_values.append(roc_auc_score(target, pred))
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

        #Generate some fake data
        #This makes an OrderedDict of 20 scipy.sparse.csr_matrix objects, with 10 rows and 10 columns and binary values
        od = OrderedDict()
        for i in range(20):
                row = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
                col = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
                data = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
                sp_matrix = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(10, 10))
                od[i] = sp_matrix

        #Now let's include some empty lists at the end of the Ordered Dict.

        for j in range(20, 23):
                od[j] = []

        #Calling the roc_auc_score function on all non-list values that have at least one instance of each 0/1 class
        test_roc_vals(od)
```

I can't figure out why my if/else isn't catching instances of 'only one class'. Or maybe it is, and the error is being caused by something else?

OLD:

I can't find this [in the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html). Is there a minimum number of instances per class for `roc_auc_score` in sklearn?

I'm having trouble calculating it, even when I have 10 examples in the underrepresented class.

Comment: What do you mean by "having trouble"? Post the code and sample data and full error if any.

Comment: @VivekKumar Please see the edit. I've included the error and an MWE.

Comment: Okay, several things were wrong with my MWE. Turns out, according to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931762/unexpected-behaviour-from-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-data), my initialization of the rows and columns of the sparse matrices resulted in some '2's in the data section. Also, I should have called `flatten()` on the true and pred values.

Answer (score 0):

Two things were wrong:

1) For the multilabel setting, don't forget to use `flatten()`.

2) when generating MWE data, recall initialization of a `csr_matrix` uses `coo_matrix` and sums any duplicate values in the same row/column index, according to [sascha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931762/unexpected-behaviour-from-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-data).

from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

```
def test_roc_vals(od):
        #od will be an OrderedDict with integer keys and scipy.sparse.csr_matrix OR list values
        #if the value is a list, it will be empty.
        #a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix may have only 0s or only 1s
        roc_values = []
        for i in range(len(od.keys())-1):
                print "i is: ", i,
                target = od[od.keys()[i+1]]
                pred = od[od.keys()[i]]

            if isinstance(target, list) or isinstance(pred, list):
                    print 'one of them is a list: cannot compute roc_auc_score'
                    continue
            else:   
                    target = target.toarray().flatten()
                    pred = pred.toarray().flatten()
                    if len(np.unique(target)) != 2 or len(np.unique(pred)) !=2:
                            print 'either target or pred or both contain only one class: cannot compute roc_auc_score'
                            continue
                    else:   
                            roc_values.append(roc_auc_score(target, pred))

    return roc_values

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Generate some fake data
    #This makes an OrderedDict of 20 scipy.sparse.csr_matrix objects, with 10 rows and 10 columns and binary values
    od = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(20):
            row = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
            col = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
            data = np.random.randint(2, size=9)
            sp_matrix = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))
            od[i] = sp_matrix

    #Now let's include some empty lists at the end of the Ordered Dict.

    for j in range(20, 23):
            od[j] = []

    #Calling the roc_auc_score function on all non-list values that have at least one instance of each 0/1 class
    rocvals = test_roc_vals(od)
    print rocvals
```

Or, more compactly, you could use a `try/except` instead of the multiple if statements, something like this:

```
        try:
                roc_values.append(roc_auc_score(target.toarray().flatten(), pred.toarray().flatten()))
        except: 
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `y_true` set should have many kinds of labels. For example, it should be `y_true = [1,1,0,0]` instead of `y_true =[1,1,1,1]` or `y_true =[0,0,0,0]`.